# Setting error display level on Google App Engine PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, error-handling

The error level displayed on localhost (using GoogleAppEngineLauncher) and on actual GAE public URL seem to be different: there are errors that are ignored on localhost, but caught on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

errors aren't necessarly ignored on localhost, maybe they don't appear.

Remember the localhost tries to "mimick" production... it doesn't always do so and sometimes has to use "hacks" to recreate the App Engine behavior, hacks which may create different errors.

Most of the time your errors will be available once on GAE by going to your admin console and looking at your Log Viewer.

I'm unclear as to the exact question you're asking though....  if you could specify it clearly it would help in formulating an appropriate response

Comment: thanks for your reply. I found that I can setup a php.ini file on the root directory, so I set "error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED;" in it, and now testing it out on localhost.

Comment: @dcc keep me posted, I am interested in seeing how this works.  Debugging on localhost is always a chore :P

Comment: hi, I've tested the php.ini on local, but there are still errors that are ignored locally but appear on production. I've noticed elsewhere that the PHP environment on GAE still have many issues to be fixed, so this might be one of them.